# Different Keys Point to Same Object(s) in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a custom object called `Person` that among other things contains an `NSString` field called `descriptor`, which stores what sort of person that `Person` object is (angry, sad, wild, happy, morose, etc). All of my Person objects are in an `NSMutableArray`, but I would like to store them in an `NSMutableDictionary` in such a manner:

Key: A, Object: An `NSMutableArray` where all `Person` objects have `descriptor` starting with 'A'

Key: B, Object: An `NSMutableArray` where all `Person` objects have `descriptor` starting with 'B'

Key: C, Object: An `NSMutableArray` where all `Person` objects have `descriptor` starting with 'C'
etc...

I've tried to do this in my code below, and at the comment //POINT 1, the keys and arrays seem to match up, but at //POINT 2, when I print out the complete dictionary, all the keys come up with the same values!

So I wanted to know why the `NSMutableArray` I seem to have is not being stored as I want it in the `NSMutableDictionary`?

```
- (void)buildDictionaryForIndexList {
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *personsStartingWithLetter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *indexList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSInteger loopCounter = 1;
    NSString *firstLetter = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (Person *v in persons) {
        firstLetter = [[v descriptor] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        if ([indexList containsObject:firstLetter]) {
            [personsStartingWithLetter addObject:v];
            if (loopCounter == [persons count]) {
                [tempDict setObject:personsStartingWithLetter forKey:firstLetter];
            }
        } else {
            if (loopCounter > 1) {
                //POINT 1
                NSLog(@"%@",[indexList objectAtIndex:[indexList count]-1]);
                for (Person *q in personsStartingWithLetter) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[q descriptor]);
                }
                [tempDict setObject:personsStartingWithLetter forKey:[indexList objectAtIndex:([indexList count] - 1)]];
                [personsStartingWithLetter removeAllObjects];
            }
            [indexList addObject:firstLetter];
            [personsStartingWithLetter addObject:v];
        } // else
        loopCounter++;
    } // for
     //POINT 2
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [tempDict keyEnumerator];
    for (NSString *str in enumerator) {
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
        for (Person *c in [tempDict objectForKey:str]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[c descriptor]);
        }
    }
    self.dictionary = tempDict;
} // buildDictionaryForIndexList
```

So, for example, at POINT 1 my output is:

A

Angry

Amiable

B

Belligerent

C

Cool

...

W

Wild

but at POINT 2 my output is

T

Wild

J

Wild

A

Wild

...

W

Wild

Comment: Remind me why in the world you're doing `[[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]`? Aren't there helpers for that? Like `-string`?

Comment: In fact, why are you using `autorelease` at all in that method? The lifetime of those objects is scoped to that method only, so you may as well just send them the `-release` message at the end of the method.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: Chalk it up to a poor memory management style. But, say I changed all that (and I have), I still encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `[tempDict setObject:personsStartingWithLetter forKey:[indexList objectAtIndex:([indexList count] - 1)]];` (just after point 1) to `[tempDict setObject:[[personsStartingWithLetter copy] autorelease] forKey:[indexList objectAtIndex:([indexList count] - 1)]];`. The problem is that NSDictionary copies the key, but retains the value. Therefore, if you add a mutable array to the dictionary and then change it, the array in the dictionary also changes. You need to create a non-mutable copy of the array to put in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The whole method is a bit overcomplicated.

```
- (void)buildDictionaryForIndexList 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (Person *v in persons)
    {
        NSString* firstLetter = [[v descriptor] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        NSMutableArray* personsStartingWithLetter = tempDict [firstLetter];
        if (personsStartingWithLetter == nil)
        {
            personsStartingWithLetter = [NSMutableArray array];
            tempDict [firstLetter] = personsStartingWithLetter;
        }
        [personsStartingWithLetter addObject:v];
    } // for
    self.dictionary = tempDict;
}
```

You start with an empty dictionary that will contain arrays. For every person, you check whether there is a suitable array or not, and if there isn't one, you create it. So now there *is* an array for the person, so you add it to the array. That's all.